# Understanding a recursive function involving generators

Tags: algorithm, swift, recursion

I've come across the following recursive algorithm, written here in Swift, that given an array, produces a generator that generates sub-arrays that are one element shorter than the original array. The sub arrays are created by removing one element at every index.

ie input `[1,2,3]` would return a generator that generated `[1,2] [2,3] [1,3]`.

The algorithm works, but I'm having real trouble understanding how. Could someone explain what's happening, or offer advice on how to analyze or understand it? Thanks in advance

```
// Main algorithm 
func smaller1<T>(xs:[T]) -> GeneratorOf<[T]> {
    if let (head, tail) = xs.decompose {

        var gen1:GeneratorOf<[T]> = one(tail)

        var gen2:GeneratorOf<[T]> = map(smaller1(tail)) {
            smallerTail in
            return [head] + smallerTail
        }
        return gen1 + gen2
    }

    return one(nil)
}


// Auxillary functions used
func map<A, B>(var generator:GeneratorOf<A>, f:A -> B) -> GeneratorOf<B> {
    return GeneratorOf {
        return generator.next().map(f)
    }
}

func one<X>(x:X?) -> GeneratorOf<X> {
    return GeneratorOf(GeneratorOfOne(x))
}
```

The code is taken from the book 'Functional Programming in Swift' by Chris Eidhof, Florian Kugler, and Wouter Swierstra

Comment: It seems this is largely a Swift specific problem. It may be a general programming issue of interest, but the code makes reference to notations that are language specific. Programming sites would be more appropriate.

Comment: As the way this algorithm is expressed requires solid understanding of the Swift programming language, it is not a suitable question for [cs.se]. I am therefore migrating it to [so] where it is on-topic as a question about understanding a short piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an array [a_1,…,a_n], the code:

- Generates the sub-array [a_2,…,a_n];
- For each sub-array B of [a_2,…,a_n] (generated recursively), generates [a_1] + B.

For example, given the array [1,2,3], we:

- Generate [2,3];
- For each sub-array B of [2,3] (namely, [3] and [2]), generate [1] + B (this generates [1,3] and [1,2]).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's really helpful. Could you explain at all the process you used for breaking down the algorithm in order to understand it?

Comment: I just read the code. It also helps to know what the code is trying to accomplish. More generally, if you are stuck, you should try to run bits of the code and see what they output – add debug printouts to the code. This can help you understand what's going on.